# echo %ERRORLEVEL% in Windows shell scripting versus echo $? in Linux: are there any differences in behavior?

Tags: linux, windows, shell, error-handling, scripting

If I do in Windows:

```
C:\>dir z:
Drive path not found.

C:\>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
1

C:\>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
1

C:\>echo %ERRORLEVEL%
1
```

But if I do in Linux:

```
Luis@Kenobi ~/Temporal/SUDO/Pruebas
$ ls /ppp
ls: unable to access /ppp: No such file or directory

Luis@Kenobi ~/Temporal/SUDO/Pruebas
$ echo $?
2

Luis@Kenobi ~/Temporal/SUDO/Pruebas
$ echo $?
0

Luis@Kenobi ~/Temporal/SUDO/Pruebas
$ echo $?
0
```

This is supposed to happen because `echo` in Windows does not modify the variable associated to the error level of the last command.
It has been unexpected for me, and it took me a while to debug a script, because I was thinking the main behavior **would be the same**.

As long as I use to program often some scripts on Windows or Linux shell, is there **any other crucial difference(s)** to note about the main error level operating system variable management?

Comment: If you know Linux shell scripting only 10-20% of your knowledge will transfer to Windows cmd, and vice versa.  It's best to assume they're completely different environments with some overlap and not generally similar.

Answer (score 3):

**For Windows**

**%ERRORLEVEL% will be 1 in case of failure of any commands and will change to 0 after successful execution of command except `echo`**

> In windows echo is a curious command. Let's see how it behaves

When echo command works

> If errorlevel is 0 before echo, after echo, errorlevel will be 0 (the obvious case)
>
> If errorlevel is 1 before echo, after echo, errorlevel will be 1. Echo does not change errorlevel

**When echo command "fails"**

Can echo fail? Let's create a case where it "fails". Open two command windows on the same directory. In first one run `pause > file.txt` to generate a file and place a lock on it while the pause command is waiting a keypress. In second command window run `echo something > file.txt`. In this case, the echo command will fail, as the first command window hold a lock on the file, so the second one is not able to write to the file. Properly talking the echo has not failed, but the redirection does, but just to see what happens

> If errorlevel is 1 before running echo, it is still 1 after the echo (the obvious case)
>
> If errolevel is 0 before running echo, it is still 0 after the echo

So, it seems that the echo command behaves identically in the two cases

BUT if we change the way echo is executed to

```
echo something && echo works || echo fails
```

then the behaviour changes a bit

When echo command works

No difference. errorlevel will not change, keeping the value it had before running the echo command.

When echo command "fails"

Using the `echo something > file && echo works || echo fails` then, if errorlevel is 1 before running echo, it keeps its value.

> But if errorlevel is 0 and the echo command fails, in this case, with
>   this construct of the command, errorlevel will show the failure and
>   change its value to 1

**For Linux**

With every unsuccessful commands output `$? value` will set to nonzero & with every successful output of the command it will be set to `zero`